# IronPython: How to call a function that expects an array of value-types?

Tags: arrays, ironpython, il, boxing

I have come across a problem with IronPython that I can't solve. I need to call a function that takes a parameter of type array to value-type. The function-signature (in C++/CLI notation) is this:

```
static int PLGServiceInterface::PLGService::MapLowSpeedRealtimeNames(cli::array<System::String ^> ^ SignalNames, int timeout_ms, cli::array<PLGServiceInterface::LVCluster_1> ^% Channels, System::String ^% ReportText)
```

When I call the function from IronPython

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath('PLGServiceAPI.dll')

from System import String, Array
from PLGServiceInterface import PLGService, LVCluster_1

outtext = clr.Reference[String]()
outdata = clr.Reference[Array[LVCluster_1]]()
PLGService.MapLowSpeedRealtimeNames(('hello', 'world'), 300, outdata, outtext)
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: expected StrongBox[Array[LVCluster_1]], got StrongBox[Array[LVCluster_1]]
```

The error message is not very helpful but I assume the problem is that "outdata" is an array containing value types instead of reference types. Apparently IronPython doesn't know how to do the boxing in that case.

With C++/CLI I can use the function just fine:

```
using namespace System;
using PLGServiceInterface::LVCluster_1;
using PLGServiceInterface::PLGService;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    array<LVCluster_1> ^outdata;
    array<String^> ^names = gcnew array<String^>{"one", "two"};
    String ^o;

    PLGService::MapLowSpeedRealtimeNames(names, 300, outdata, o);

    Console::WriteLine(o);

    Console::Read();

    return 0;
}
```

I assume if the function would instead expect an array of references

```
array<LVCluster_1 ^> ^outdata
```

I could call it with IronPython.

Is there any way to make this work with IronPython? By the way, the assembly was created with LabView and LVCluster_1 is a LabView-Cluster (structure).

Edit:
The Intermediate Language signature of MapLowSpeedRealtimeNames is this:

```
.method public hidebysig static int32  MapLowSpeedRealtimeNames(string[...] SignalNames,
                                                                int32 timeout_ms,
                                                                [out] valuetype PLGServiceInterface.LVCluster_1[...]& Channels,
                                                                [out] string& ReportText) cil managed
```

Does anybody know what the meaning of the 3 dots in the array brackets is? When I compile a function that takes an array in C++/CLI, I only get the opening and closing brackets without the dots in between.

These dots seem suspicious to me because I also get the TypeError when calling a 
method that takes an out-parameter of type array of double(float64):

```
.method public hidebysig static int32  ReadVariables(string[...] SignalNames,
                                                     int32 timeout_ms,
                                                     [out] string& ReportText,
                                                     [out] float64[...]& Data) cil managed
```

Generates the error

```
TypeError: expected StrongBox[Array[float]], got StrongBox[Array[float]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Array.CreateInstance(LVCluster_1, length) to create the array? See example below:

```
outdata = Array.CreateInstance(LVCluster_1, 2)
```

The code above works for me, but my c++/cli function signature don't use the tracking reference (%). So if I were to re-write your function signature it would look like:

```
static int PLGServiceInterface::PLGService::MapLowSpeedRealtimeNames(cli::array<System::String ^> ^ SignalNames, int timeout_ms, cli::array<PLGServiceInterface::LVCluster_1> ^ Channels, System::String ^ ReportText)
```

Comment: This might work if "outdata" weren't an out-parameter. But in my case it is an out-parameter and therefore it doesn't make sense to create an array before calling the function. I have to use clr.Reference but I don't know how I can specify that the type in square brackets is a by-value type.

Comment: Does "outdata" have to be an out-parameter? Normally, only primitive types are pass by value. Arrays and complex objects are usually pass by reference, because it's less expensive to do so. The idea here is to create an array in managed code, pass the reference to unmanaged code, and copy the data from unmanaged code to managed code.

Comment: In the above code the array of LVCluster_1 is not copied by value. A reference to the outdata-handle is passed to the function (via the "Channels" parameter). The function will then modify the handle so it points to an array-object which it created internally. Still your idea could work because I know that the outdata-array must have the same number of elements as the array of strings that is passed in as the first parameter. But what would you do if you didn't know the number of elements of the output-array? In that case you couldn't pre-allocate the memory in the calling function.

Comment: If I did not know the number of elements in the output array:  **In C#**, I would use the output parameter, or return the reference as the return type.  **In IronPython**, I would return the reference as the return type, because I don't think it support output parameters.  In your case, I would recommend modifying your code to be more IronPython friendly. Instead of using output parameters, define an object with the values you want to return, populate that object in your C#, or native code, and return that object. That way all you have to do in IronPython is get values from that return object.