# Can't call a function which takes a parameter of a type that is defined in a different assembly

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, ironpython

Consider there are 2 assemblies written in C#. The code for the first assembly is:

```
namespace VSInterface
{
    public class X
    {

    }
}
```

The code for the second assembly is:

```
namespace VSInterface
{
    public class TestIPY
    {
        public static void foo(X bar)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

When I call the function foo from the following IPY code:

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r"SomeFolder\FirstAssembly.dll")
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r"SomeOtherFolder\SecondAssembly.dll")

from VSInterface import TestIPY, X

TestIPY.foo(X())
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: expected X, got X
```

I only get this error when the classes `X` and `TestIPY` are defined in separate assemblies. The code works fine when they are defined in the same assembly.

Why is it not working when the classes are contained in separated assemblies?

I guess that this issue is somewhat related to this one, which I reported last year:
[IronPython: How to call a function that expects an array of value-types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29305150/ironpython-how-to-call-a-function-that-expects-an-array-of-value-types)

I gave up searching for a solution for the linked issue because I thought that there was some funny stuff going on with LabView. However, now I want to interface with my own C# code and I get a similar (the same?) error.

**Update 12.01.2016**
Unfortunately this issue is not entirely resolved for me. The problem occurs when `SomeOtherFolder` contains a copy of `FirstAssembly.dll`. This can be solved easily by deleting `FirstAssembly`from `SomeOtherFolder`. *However*, the problem **also** occurs if `SomeFolder` (I realize I should have chosen better directory names...) is a relative path. This was a problem for me because I have to use relative paths for my project. I could avoid this problem by using the following code to import the assembly:

```
import clr
import os
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(os.path.abspath(r"SomeFolder\FirstAssembly.dll"))
```

I don't really understand why it doesn't work when relative paths are used and I'm not sure whether this is a bug in IronPython or not.

Comment: `SomeFolder` and `SomeOtherFolder` - does `SomeOtherFolder` contain it's own copy of `FirstAssembly.dll`?  It may be loading a different one as a dependency of `SecondAssembly.dll`?

Comment: Do you have to create your references at run-time?
If you are using VS Studio you could possibly use the [Add Reference] feature and have your reference built in at compile time and then use the "using" statement instead of the "import". This could solve your issue. I also notice that both have the same namespace. Did you try changing the namespace of one to see if you still get the problem?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes, `SomeOtherFolder`contained a copy of `FirstAssembly.dll` and this was causing the problem. See BendEg's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurse, when the assembly `FirstAssembly.dll` is in the folder: `SomeFolder` and `SomeOtherFolder`. Because in that case the type `X` get's loaded twice and it does not match any more to the signiture of `foo`.

Comment: You are correct. "SomeOtherFolder" contained a copy of "FirstAssembly.dll" because the "CopyLocal" option in Visual Studio was set to true. After I deleted the .dll file it works. Thanks!